# Get list of subscribers with Chilli Creams Hotchocolate graphql

Tags: hotchocolate

When using the [in memory subscriptions for HotChocolate.](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/defining-a-schema/subscriptions/#in-memory-provider)

Is it possible / how can I keep track of who is subscribed to a particular subscription? Is there an on connected event that I can hook into or something similar?